# Adding text as describtion to listbox items VB

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I'm trying to add text as a description to my items, but I don't know how to do it. 
here is my code:

```
    BMRList.Items.Insert(0, bmrCalc.CalcBasMetabolicRateBMR)
    BMRList.Items.Insert(1, bmrCalc.MaintainWeightCalories)
    BMRList.Items.Insert(2, bmrCalc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories(500, True))
    BMRList.Items.Insert(3, bmrCalc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories(1000, True))
    BMRList.Items.Insert(4, bmrCalc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories(500, False))
    BMRList.Items.Insert(5, bmrCalc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories(1000, False))
```

This will result in Boolean numbers as items. What I want to do is to
 add a text to the left of the items. For example

```
"Your BMR is:"   (item1)  
"To maintain your weight you need" (item2) 
"Calories to lose 0,5 kg per week" (item3)
```

bmrcalc LoseOrGainWeightCalories Method:

```
   Public Function LoseOrGainWeightCalories(ByRef weightt As Double, lose As Boolean) As Double


    Dim Maintain As Double = MaintainWeightCalories()

    Dim test As Double
    If lose = True Then
        test = Maintain - weightt

        Return test
    Else
        Return Maintain + weightt
    End If

End Function
```

I do have two classes: Main Class and CalorieCalc class. All output must happen from the main class. The CalorieClass must not depend on the Main Class. The CalorieCalc class should only have fields(instance variables) for saving input. No output variables are to be used in the CalorieCalc class.

I hope you get the idea. I'm using VB

Comment: Can you show us what the "bmrCalc" is? Because it is the bmrCalc.LoseOrGainWeightCalories's string you are adding to the list.

Comment: Why dont you just change the item text? `BMRList.Items.item(0) = "Your BMR is: " & BMRList.Items.item(0)`.  And did you mean "This will result in INTEGER numbers as items." ?

As far as i know listboxitems as just strings. for more complex action you might wanna consider a ListView.

Comment: Like that: `BMRList.Items.Insert(0, "Text" & bmrCalc.CalcBasMetabolicRateBMR)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that:

```
BMRList.Items.Insert(0, "Text" & bmrCalc.CalcBasMetabolicRateBMR)
```